# Why is the branching ratio $H\to WW$ much larger than $H \to ZZ$?

Tags: particle-physics, standard-model, feynman-diagrams, higgs, electroweak

The Higgs decay to a pair of W bosons is the second-largest ($\mathrm{BR}(H\to WW)=21.8\%$), while the one to $Z$ bosons is so much smaller ($\mathrm{BR}(H\to ZZ)=2.7\%$). Is there an obvious reason why?

Also, why can't a Higgs decay to a pair of top quarks, where one would be off mass-shell, just like in the $H\to WW$ and $H\to ZZ$ case?

Comment: Is it because of a difference in the propagator factor, or the coupling to the Higgs?

Comment: It would be helpful if you attested the precise origin of your (suspect?) discrepant ratios. Are you relay comparing ZZ* to WW*? from [this](https://pdg.lbl.gov/2021/tables/contents_tables.html)? You may compare the amps [directly](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s100529801038).

Comment: The ratio of propagators is crudely a factor of 2, squared to a ratio of 4. There is an identical particle suppression of a factor of 2 for the Z mode, amounting to another factor of 4. It should be in the relevant papers.

Answer (score 0):

The tree-level couplings of Higgs gauge bosons and top quark indicate that $H\rightarrow WW, ZZ, t\bar{t}$ has to be dominant decay channels. This notion gets challenged as the observed Higgs mass was surprisingly very low for these decay channels $m_H < 2m_{W,Z}$(for example if decay to $Z$ bosons would be possible only when $m_H > 180$ GeV). Hence, decay to these particles is possible through the off-shell process (for example, decay to top quark is kinematically forbidden). **The intermediate $W$ boson being less massive (compared to $Z$ boson) is preferred which ends up with 2 leptons and corresponding neutrinos.** If the question is, why can't we have one on-shell decay of bosons, then the answer would be on the arguments of phase space. Decaying into the same particles reduces the phase space and is preferred.

Comment: Hi Prajwal, thanks for your answer, unfortunately my questions are still not answered here. The fact that the Higgs can decay to a pair of W and Z is understood, where one of the bosons in the pair is off-shell. But what makes the branching ratio of $H\rightarrow ZZ$ and $H\rightarrow WW$ a factor of 10 differen?. Also if the latter decays are possible, why can't we have $H\rightarrow t\bar t$, where one top quark is off-shell?

Comment: Also, since the coupling to the Higgs is proportional to the mass of the particle, shouldn't the Higgs prefer to decay to a Z rather than a W?

Comment: I hope this [paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1503.01060.pdf) will be helpful